# Publish Android app after crosswalk removal and make it updatable

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-services, apk

I have decided to remove [Crosswalk Webview](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) from my `Cordova` application.

Now I have tried to publish the new updated version to "Console Play Store" and after that it says that **users won't be able to update from the published latest old version**.
Indeed, I also tried from my phone to upgrade from my old version to the new one and it says that package could be corrupted. Otherwise, if I remove the old one and install the new one everything works fine.

I used the same keystore to sign the application. The only thing that has changed is the original "unsigned" apk (from the old Crosswalk ARM version to the standard cordova `android-release-unsigned.apk`).

Could you please help me to find a way to publish my new app version and let users to update from latest old crosswalk arm version they already have?

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem and I'm still finding a solution

Comment: Based from this [thread](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en), when you unpublish an app, existing users can still use your app and receive app updates. However, your app won’t be available for new users to find and download on Google Play. Here's a related [ppost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290083/how-do-i-publish-an-updated-version-of-my-existing-ionic-app-on-google-play-stor) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Check your app's version code. Since crosswalk uses multiple apks, it's version code is multiplied by 10 (see below). When you remove crosswalk, version code becomes normal, which means lose one digit. Newer app's version code should be larger!

So I just put larger number manually into config.xml. (widget tag's android-versionCode attribute)

```
// these are equations from gradle file
armv7 {
    versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
}
x86 {
    versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
}
```